# Diffuse texture baking wrong

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-baking, baking

Made this procedural chameleon texture but when I try to bake the colors it's completely wrong? Any idea what this could be caused by?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Impressive node tree and lovely result!
Can we see the baking settings please, or, if it would be easier you could upload the blend file - I know https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ is one place that is popular here.

Comment: Bake Type is Diffuse, and for Influence the only contributor is Color. The rest is default settings

Comment: How were the objects relatively to each other? Also have you checked normal? Consider adding a screenshot with meshes and the bake panel.

Comment: @lemon By the objects, you mean the eyes and the spine? There are no separated objects other than those. Just tried recalculating normals outside and same result. Added a picture but not sure if that's what you meant

Comment: @Fatcat, I though you were baking onto another mesh. So forget it. Consider uploading your file as Ben said in first comment.

Comment: When you're baking only colors, you don't want Direct and Indirect in Diffuse settings. Other than that it looks like there's a different UV map present on the object. If you want to bake to a different UV, make sure it's selected and the source one has camera icon set to it. If you don't want to bake to a different one, make sure camera icon is next to selected UV channel

Comment: Woops. Direct and Indirect were off originally, I just tested to do it with and forgot to turn it off again for the screenshot. My bad. I can only see 1 UV map in the list @MrZak
Here is the blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vw3KMMka

Comment: Can't seem to edit the above comment to mention you @lemon , just making sure the reply is seen. Posted the blend file above

Comment: @Fatcat, so this is ok?

Answer (score 1):

When I bake this from the provided blend file, it works.  As such this doesn't directly answer the question, but it's too large for a comment and might be helpful so I will post it anyway - if a proper "here's what you did wrong and here's how to fix it" answer shows up and this no longer seems useful please feel free to delete it.

Here are the steps I took from loading the blend file to having a baked output png saved and the chameleon displaying properly in cycles mode using the texture rather than the nodes:

1. In the node view of the 'Procedural' material, add a texture setup to receive the bake.  This texture is blank, and in this case is a 1024x1024 black png file which I saved to disk so it existed (blender is sometimes a bit weird about having its files exist before writing to them, also, cycles seems to render from-file rather than from-memory).  It's fine that this isn't connected to anything at this stage [image: Texture setup]
2. Select the texture node.  Just click on it so the BakedOutput node has a white outline.  This step is important because otherwise it might put the bake somewhere else - probably on top of the chameleon skin texture or something equally unhelpful.
3. Change the render engine to Cycles.
4. Set up for diffuse color baking with no lighting information.  I used these settings: [image: Bake Settings]
5. Press Bake, and wait for it to complete
6. Save the resulting BakedOutput.png or whatever else you have called it.  First because it's good practice and it's easy to lose the bake if you don't, but also, perhaps more importantly, because as mentioned Cycles likes to render with the black blank texture if that's what's on disk.
7. Attach the texture node to the Color input in the Procedural material to check it works - you may wish to use the texture elsewhere instead, and preserve the Procedural material and just switch to the new one, but I didn't do that, I just swapped the Color input to be faster and more sure it would work.  Screenshot shows disconnected procedural result and connected texture node: [image: Final node tree]

As to what you did that caused your issue I am unsure.  I cannot seem to reproduce it - even baking with lighting information included just produces a badly lit output, rather than the mis-arranged image with the wrong parts mapped shown in the question.  I attempted baking with incorrect texture coordinates but that didn't seem to do it either.  There's only one UVMap provided so I couldn't bake using the wrong one of those... I'm not sure if I can answer the question, so feel free to ignore this answer if it isn't helpful.  Perhaps try recording your own steps and then following mine and see if we get the same result.

I -did- notice that the bake is different (and worse looking, much further away from original procedural output) baked from Edit mode instead of Object mode.  I suspect this might have something to do with it, but it still doesn't match your original image.  Perhaps the pose or armature is involved.

Comment: That's odd, I did all the same steps but I'm still getting the same result. I really wonder what's wrong. If you still have it, could you send the successful baked image? Would be very apppreciated!

Comment: Ok, NOW I have your problem.  That is -weird-.  Investigating further now I reproduced it by accident!

Comment: Oh @Ben did you figure out what exactly was causing it or was it completely random?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting any additional materials on the mesh.
You might be receiving an error like

`No active image found in material "Wheels" (0) for object "fifty.001"`

In my case, I just deleted that material from the mesh, and then the bake worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Blending **Ambient Occlusion** with **procedural texture** via **MixRGB** node caused me a problem exactly like this one. I had to remove AO and then bake a diffuse map.

You can check this up by baking an AO map, if your AO bake covers exactly the same areas where your diffuse bake had problems you have found your culprit.

Comment: Is this a bug of is there a sensible reason for this behavior? Also: Welcome and thanks for your input :)